# Launch PDF viewer from within a Mathematica Notebook

Tags: pdf-format, hyperlink

I would like to view a designated PDF document by clicking on a hyperlink in a Mathematica notebook.

I am able to open the designated PDF document using SystemOpen["E:\OneDrive\Learning Mathematica\Tutorial.pdf"] which opens the document using the system default PDF viewer configured on my local machine. This is acceptable. My only problem is that I don't want to see the SystemOpen[] command in my notebook cell. I want to launch the PDF document viewer by clicking on a hyperlink (or something similar) which I am able to label with some user friendly text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.3\\Documentation\\English\\
 System\\ExampleData\\mathematica.pdf"; 

Button[Style["mathematica.pdf", "Subsection"], SystemOpen[url], 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]

To replace the input cell (`url = ...; Button[...]`) with the button object, highlight the cell contents and, then either (1) select `Evaluate in Place` from the `Evaluation` menu, or (2) use the keyboard short-cut Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly. Very instructive!